# Drag and drop for web application on iPhone/android device

Tags: iphone, android, html, web-applications, drag-and-drop

I am working on a web application which has to work on iPhone,android as well as desktop browser.I should integrate drag and drop functionality for several images on the webpage.There should also be several droppables to accept these images.I have tried jQuery's Draggable and Droppable features to implement this, but that is working fine only on desktop but not on iPhone/Android devices.[This link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [one more link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) are the sources of libraries that i used for drag and drop.Can any one please let me know are there any libraries/APIs which offer the same functionality as jQuery's drag and drop for touch sensitive devices like iPhone/Android along with desktop.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS, this seems to work great in Chrome on Android. I'm not sure about iOS.

Demos - http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/index.html

Repo with documentation - https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but i'm afraid is not possible to do drag and drop on a web application for android/iphone my recommendation is make an app for android/iphone and implement the drag and drop there.

Comment: Actually thats for an app made for iphone not for the browser in Iphone so make sure first >_>

Comment: Sorry wrong link, but I've seen it done on a WebApp. So I know it's possible. Just can't find the link in my bookmarks. Found some: http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/. Here is an other SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619790/drag-and-drop-in-mobilesafari

Comment: It's certainly possible in Android 3.0, and has been since at least March, when I first converted a web app from desktop-only to support Android. Drag and drop is a bit slow on Android 3.0 web applications, but it does work.