# Drag & Drop on Safari iOS: Is much of it handled for me or will I have to code most of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, drag-and-drop

Are there events specifically for Safari that can tell me when a HTML element is being dragged & dropped?

In order to perform drag & drop on Safari on an iPad...do I have to do such things as detect the mousemove event on a HTML element then update the HTML elements x,y pos as the mouse moves.

Or is all this handled by the browser through events or something?

Also is there an event that is triggered when I drop an object onto another object? Do both objects fire an event(for eg something like ItemDroppedEvent for the element being dragged & ItemDroppedEvent for the HTML element that received the drop element)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop in MobileSafari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619790/drag-and-drop-in-mobilesafari)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Safari supports

```
ondragstart
ondrag
ondragend
```

You can find more about it here : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511

Answer (score 2):

actually the link slickrick posted to apple develpoer page says on first line that

"drag events are NOT supported on mobile safari and need to be simulated via low level touch events"

one library that does this for you in multiplatform way is hammer.js for example http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/